# Is it wrong to write a linear system as below?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Suppose we have the following linear system

\begin{align}
2x_1+3x_2+4x_3&=1\\
2x_2-3x_3&=6\\
0&=0.\\
\end{align}

Is it wrong to write the above linear system by including all the zero coefficients as below

\begin{align}
2x_1+3x_2+4x_3&=1\\
0x_1+2x_2-3x_3&=6\\
0x_1+0x_2+0x_3&=0\\
\end{align}

instead?

Comment: It is correct, it just uses more symbols.

Comment: It's not wrong, it only wastes ink.

Comment: It was already answered in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586948/is-this-equation-is-linear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly it is correct. If it is easier for you to understand the equations this way, do so.

It's what, in effect, we do when we construct the augmented coefficient matrix of a system of equations, using $0$'s to represent the coefficients of the appropriate variables.

For example, the augmented coefficient matrix corresponding to your system of equations is given by $$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 & 4 &\mid & 1\\ 0 & 2 & -3 &\mid& 6 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 &\mid & 0\end{pmatrix}$$